Can I have contacts without email and first name?
Is there a way to change the contact validation to allow only last names like "Mr. Smith"?

It's hardcoded at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/92aa28150564135bd58b63c68914f3fd0763908a/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Individual.php#L107 but maybe it's time this rule was updated since you can create contacts with the api that just have last name, and openid isn't enabled by default.
If you have an email address, or enter a fake one, it will save with just last name.
Or you could enable the openid field at admin - customize - display prefs, and then enter a fake url into that field on the form and then it will save with just a last name.
Note you may want to update your dedupe rules though to include some other field if you really want just last names.

I'd be happy if that issue is reconsidered within the next releases.
